# Module/theme installation error

Tags: 7, installation, files

I couldn't installed new modules/theme, when i try to install it asks for FTP request for server. Here I spell out what I did,

At first, Update manager module was not enabled. As I couldn't find "install new module" link in the module page, I enabled the update manager module. Now, I got "install new module". The problem starts here: In the module's page, it shows some warnings.

> fileowner()[function.fileowner]:stat failed for temporary

[image]

When I tried to install a new module (on click "install new module"), it shows warnings as follows.

[image]

I found [Installing modules without FTP](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37018/installing-modules-without-ftp), but I couldn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Did you check your tmp folder make sure its writable?

Comment: It's just a directory permissions issue, check the temp folder path here `/admin/config/media/file-system` and make sure that the folder exists and is writeable by the web server group.  You can verify that Drupal can't write to the temp folder here `/admin/reports/status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the write permissions for the directory `/admin/config/media/file-system`. So, I got to change the write permissions to `files` directory that appears in `/sites/default path`
- change permissions from `dwrx-rx-x` to `dwrx-wrx-wrx`

If every thing goes well, you will no longer see the warning. Now, you are ready to install the new modules/themes.